# Drawing string to bounded area? Java

Tags: java, string, graphics, paint, rect

Here is my paint method.

```
public void paint(Graphics pane)
{
    pane.setColor(Color.black);
    pane.drawRect(x, y-HEIGHT, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    if(name!=null)
        pane.drawString(getName(), x, y-50);

    }
}
```

I would like for the string returned from getName() method to be bounded within the rectangle I have created, rather than just starting where the rectangle starts then writing over the edge.

Comment: Start with [Working with Text APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/index.html) and [Drawing Multiple Lines of Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/drawmulstring.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer dear god, is that the only way?

Comment: You thought it might be easy? Rendering text is probably the single most complicated thing you can do in any graphical framework...Try changing the font, DPI, anti-aliasing, etc...so, yep, that's the place to start ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Graphics `setClip()` method to set the clipping pane so the text will be within the rectangle, however, any excess will simply be clipped off. In order to get it to fit perfectly you will have to calculate the best font size. Check out the `FontMetrics` class to help you with the calculations.